# What characters are allowed in Haskell function names?

Tags: haskell

What is a valid name for a function?

Examples

```
-- works
let µ x = x * x  
let ö x = x * x

-- doesn't work  
let € x = x * x  
let § x = x * x
```

I am not sure, but my hunch is that Haskell doesn't allow Unicode function names, does it?
(Unicode like in http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~nad/listings/lib-0.4/Data.List.html)

Comment: I think this would vary depending on the compiler. Which one are you using?

Comment: Your keyboard layout tells me you're German ;) US keyboards neither have "§" nor "ö" nor "µ" nor "€".

Comment: @fuz Swedish/Finnish layout also has all of those.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From [the Haskell report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/lexemes.html):

> Haskell uses the Unicode character set. However, source programs are currently biased toward the ASCII character set used in earlier versions of Haskell .

Recent versions of GHC seem to be fine with unicode (at least in the form of UTF-8):

```
Prelude> let пять=5; два=2; умножить=(*); на=id in пять `умножить` на два
10
```

(In case you wonder, «пять `умножить` на два» means «five `multiplied` by two» in Russian.)

Your examples do not work because those character are «symbols» and  can be used in infix operators but not in function names. See "uniSymbol" category in the report.

```
Prelude> let x € y = x * y in 2 € 5
10
```

Comment: tl;dr @mrsteve: Haskell treats identifiers consisting of punctuation (except `'`) to be infix operators.

Comment: In particular, `isAlphaNum '€' == False`, whereas `isAlphaNum 'ж' == True`. Both € and § are in ISO/IEC_8859-15, btw, which is quite standard (in the non-US western world)

Comment: When you use non-ASCII characters as a parameter name and bind a function to the parameter, you can use it as an infix operator. Here's an example that checks whether a function is associative: `asc (♥) a b c = a ♥ (b ♥ c) == (a ♥ b) ♥ c`. Call it like this: `asc (+) 1 2 3`