# What characters are allowed in function names etc?

Tags: elm

As the title says, which characters are allowed in identifiers (function, variable, and record field names)? `aöø` all seem to be fine, as do `'_9` if not the first character. `<$;%` do not. Is it documented somewhere which ranges/blocks of unicode characters and symbols are allowed?

Follow-up question: which characters are allowed in infix operators?

Answer (score 4):

So, after reading the [Haskell specs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023485/what-characters-are-allowed-in-haskell-function-names) (which can be assumed has influenced Elm), the [JavaScript specs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/what-characters-are-valid-for-javascript-variable-names), and trial and error, I have arrived at the following rules:

- An identifier must begin with a character from the unicode categories:

  - Uppercase letter (Lu) (modules, types)
  - Lowercase letter (Ll) (functions, variables)
  - Titlecase letter (Lt) (modules, types)
- The rest of the characters must belong to any of the following categories:

  - Uppercase letter (Lu)
  - Lowercase letter (Ll)
  - Titlecase letter (Lt)
  - Modifier letter (Lm)
  - Other letter (Lo)
  - Decimal digit number (Nd)
  - Letter number (Nl)
  - Or be `_` (except for in module names).

Technically "Other number" (No) seems to also be valid in Elm, but it crashes after it's been compiled to JavaScript.

I used [this tool](https://marcelogibson.com/stackoverflow/unicode_hack.js) to get the ranges for each category.

Comment: Primes (') will be disallowed from 0.18 https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-platform/blob/master/upgrade-docs/0.18.md#no-more-primes